# Python 3 logging - is it possible to split the module name?

Tags: python, logging, formatting

is it possible to split the module name string in a logging.Formatter?

For example, I have a module with a corresponding logger named `foo.bar.baz` (basically by using `__name__`):

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("foo.bar.baz")

logger.info("Test")
```

and a main file that imports the module `foo` and does some formatting:

```
import logging
import foo

logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
handler = logging.StreamHandler()

streamFormat = logging.Formatter('[{0}, {1}]: {2}'.format("{name}".split(".")[-1], "{levelname}", "{message}"), style='{')
handler.setFormatter(streamFormat)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

What I try to achieve now is this:

```
[baz, INFO]: Test
```

but what I get is this:

```
[foo.bar.baz, INFO]: Test
```

I think the actual string is unknown during the formatting process, which would explain why the split operation does not work:

```
['foo.bar.baz']
```

Does anyone know if there is another way to get rid of the first part of the module path?

**EDIT:** Thank you napuzba for the helpful hint! The only thing I had to add to his suggestion was a new attribute called `lname` of the record object and use it in the format string.

```
import logging
import foo

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def __init__(self, fmt=None, datefmt=None, style="%"):
        # Calling the constructor of logging.Formatter
        super().__init__(fmt, datefmt, style)

    def format(self, record):
        # This is the only line I added
        record.lname = record.__dict__['name'].split(".")[-1]
        # Adding lines from logging.Formatter.format(record) here
        [...]

logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
handler = logging.StreamHandler()

streamFormat = logging.MyFormatter('[{0}, {1}]: {2}'.format("{lname}", "{levelname}", "{message}"), style='{')
handler.setFormatter(streamFormat)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

The missing lines of `logging.Formatter.format(record)` can by found on [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L562). It's just copy & paste, if there is a more convenient way to do this, let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inherit from `logging.Formatter` and override `format(record)` to your needs.

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(fmt):
        super(fmt)
    def format(record):
        return "My format" # use record and fmt
```